# Table View Cell Can't Pull Value from Textfield

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am working with a CustomCell swift file which dictates what shows up in a table view cell on a view controller. Specifically, all the custom cells in the table view cell have been designed in .xib files for which CustomCell is the custom class. The problem is when I add a textfield .xib into one of the cells, I am not able to store the value of what is typed into the textfield because the textfield does not communicate with the view controller's TextFieldDelegate, but rather the CustomCell Class. Is there a way I am able to store the value for the textfield from the .xib? My explanation might be confusing or with lack of information so please ask if it is still unclear.

Comment: "when I add a `textfield .xib`" - textfield is an xib?

Comment: stop using xibs already.  Storyboards have been around for years.  If you use a prototype cell in a storyboard this is simple drag and drop.  If you want to use xib file then you will need to set the text field delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Paulw11 I am also using a storyboard, and not solely xibs. I am not sure what you mean by drag and drop - can you explain further? And am I able to set the textfield delegate specifically for the cell row that I need?

Comment: If your text field is in a prototype cell in your storyboard, simply drag from the text field's `delegate` outlet to your view controller object.  If you want the delegate set for a specific row and not a cell type then you need to set the delegate in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: you can use delegate methods for getting value of textfield